# How to display responsive collapse icon in Bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am trying to display the collapse icon when someone will display my website on iPhone:

```
    <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".bs-navbar-collapse">
       <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="bs-navbar-collapse">
     <ul class="nav.navbar-nav">
       <li>Create An Account</li>
       <li>Sign in</li>
     </ul>
    </div>
```

But even if I resize the window as much as I can, the icon will still doesn't appear... do I miss something? Twitter Bootstrap is loaded.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the sourrounding `nav`element with attributes.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation"></nav>
```

[Working Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/120368)

You have to closely follow the markup shown [here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar).